# What is the use of get(0) in OnResult() method of SpeechRecognizer?

Tags: java, android

I am working on speech to text recognition. In `OnResults()` method of speechRecognizer, what is the use of `result.get(0)` as specified in the below code snippet. I found out that it is used to get the first result but what does that actually mean?

```
@Override
public void onResults(Bundle results)  {
    ArrayList<String> result = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
    if(result != null){
        edittext.setText(result.get(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes speech recognizers give multiple results in descending probability. For example, "Celery Production" vs. "Cell Reproduction."

Answer (score 1):

"ArrayList from the Bundle [...] are the possible recognition results, where the first element **is the most likely candidate**." [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer#RESULTS_RECOGNITION]

You could also look at the results and determine by your own heuristic which is the most likely candidate, but index:0 is what the Recognizer deemed most likely.